# Render "hard" edges using custom shader

Tags: three.js, shader

I'd like to reproduce the effect created by using `THREE.EdgesHelper` (drawing a boundary on "hard" object edges), but using a custom shader rather than adding a separate `THREE.Line` object. Essentially I'd like to do what's done in [this demo](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_wireframe), but only for the "hard" boundaries; e.g. boundaries that are not between two coplanar faces

Approach: apply similar routine to `EdgesHelper`, but mark vertices that are in hard edges with a custom attribute (e.g. `isEdge`); probably need to use `BufferGeometry`, since regular `Geometry` allows re-use of vertices in multiple faces, but `BufferGeometry` duplicates vertices such that each vertex is part of only one face (at least, this is my understanding; the documentation isn't explicit).

Progress so far:

1. Reproduced the effect in the wireframe materials example, but using `BufferGeometry`:\
   [http://jsfiddle.net/ogav6o77/\](http://jsfiddle.net/ogav6o77/%5C)

   ```js
       function BufferEdgesHelper(geometry) {
           
           var positions = geometry.attributes.position.array;
           var normals = geometry.attributes.normal.array;
           
           // Build new attribute storing barycentric coordinates
           // for each vertex
           var centers = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array( 3 * positions.length ), 3);
           for( var f = 0; f < positions.length; f += 9 ) {
               centers.array[ f + 0 ] = 1;
               centers.array[ f + 1 ] = 0;
               centers.array[ f + 2 ] = 0;

               centers.array[ f + 3 ] = 0;
               centers.array[ f + 4 ] = 1;
               centers.array[ f + 5 ] = 0;

               centers.array[ f + 6 ] = 0;
               centers.array[ f + 7 ] = 0;
               centers.array[ f + 8 ] = 1;
           }
           geometry.addAttribute( 'center', centers );

       }

       // Build geometry 
       var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
       geometry.computeFaceNormals();
       geometry.computeTangents();
       geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry);
       BufferEdgesHelper(geometry);

       // Build shader
       var vertexShader = document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent;
       var fragmentShader = document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent;

       var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { 
           uniforms: {}, 
           attributes: {
               'center': { type: 'v3', value: null,  boundTo: 'faceVertices' }
           }, 
           vertexShader: vertexShader, 
           fragmentShader: fragmentShader 
       } );

       var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

       // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       // (Boilerplate)

       var scene = new THREE.Scene();
       var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 
                                                window.innerWidth / 
                                                window.innerHeight, 
                                                0.1, 1000);

       var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
       renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
       document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
       scene.add(cube);

       camera.position.z = 5;

       var render = function () {
           requestAnimationFrame(render);
           cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
           cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
           renderer.render(scene, camera);
       };

       render();
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r100/three.min.js"></script>
   <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
       attribute vec3 center;
       varying vec3 vCenter;
       
       void main() {

           vCenter = center;
           gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

       }
   </script>
   <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">
       #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives: enable

       varying vec3 vCenter;

       float edgeFactorTri() {

           vec3 d = fwidth(vCenter.xyz);
           vec3 a3 = smoothstep(vec3(0.0), d * 1.5, vCenter.xyz);
           return min(min(a3.x, a3.y), a3.z);

       }

       void main() {
           gl_FragColor.rgb = mix(vec3(1.0), vec3(0.2), edgeFactorTri());
           gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
       }
   </script>
   ```
2. Port the logic of `EdgesHelper` to a "`BufferEdgesHelper`" function that works with `BufferGeometry` (but still use it to create a `THREE.Line`): 
   [http://jsfiddle.net/L2aertya/\](http://jsfiddle.net/L2aertya/%5C)

   ```js
       function BufferEdgesHelper(geometry) {

           var positions = geometry.attributes.position.array;
           var normals = geometry.attributes.normal.array;

           // Build new attribute storing barycentric coordinates
           // for each vertex
           var centers = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array( 3 * positions.length ), 3);
           for( var f = 0; f < positions.length; f += 9 ) {
               centers.array[ f + 0 ] = 1;
               centers.array[ f + 1 ] = 0;
               centers.array[ f + 2 ] = 0;

               centers.array[ f + 3 ] = 0;
               centers.array[ f + 4 ] = 1;
               centers.array[ f + 5 ] = 0;

               centers.array[ f + 6 ] = 0;
               centers.array[ f + 7 ] = 0;
               centers.array[ f + 8 ] = 1;
           }
           geometry.addAttribute( 'center', centers );


           // Hash all the edges and remember which face they're associated with
           // (Adapted from THREE.EdgesHelper)
           function sortFunction ( a, b ) { 
               // Lexicographic sort
               if (a[0] - b[0] != 0) {
                   return (a[0] - b[0]);
               } else if (a[1] - b[1] != 0) { 
                   return (a[1] - b[1]);
               } else { 
                   return (a[2] - b[2]);
               }
           }
           var edge = [ 0, 0 ];
           var hash = {};
           var face;
           var numEdges = 0;

           for (var i = 0; i < positions.length/9; i++) {
               var a = i * 9 
               face = [ [ positions[a+0], positions[a+1], positions[a+2] ] ,
                        [ positions[a+3], positions[a+4], positions[a+5] ] ,
                        [ positions[a+6], positions[a+7], positions[a+8] ] ];
               for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                   var k = (j + 1) % 3;
                   var b = j * 3
                   var c = k * 3
                   edge[ 0 ] = face[ j ];
                   edge[ 1 ] = face[ k ];
                   edge.sort( sortFunction );
                   key = edge[0] + ' | ' + edge[1];
                   if ( hash[ key ] == undefined ) {
                       hash[ key ] = { vert1: a + b, vert2: a + c, face1: a, face2: undefined };
                       numEdges++;
                   } else { 
                       hash[ key ].face2 = a;
                   }
               }
           }

           // Build a new geometry containing only the "hard" edges
           var geometry2 = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
           var coords = new Float32Array( numEdges * 2 * 3 );
           var index = 0;
           for (key in hash) {
               h = hash[key];
               
               // ditch any edges that are bordered by two coplanar faces
               if ( h.face2 !== undefined ) {
                   normal1 = new THREE.Vector3(normals[h.face1+0], normals[h.face1+1], normals[h.face1+2]);
                   normal2 = new THREE.Vector3(normals[h.face2+0], normals[h.face2+1], normals[h.face2+2]);
                   if ( normal1.dot( normal2 ) >= 0.9999 ) { continue; }
               }

               coords[ index ++ ] = positions[h.vert1+0];
               coords[ index ++ ] = positions[h.vert1+1];
               coords[ index ++ ] = positions[h.vert1+2];

               coords[ index ++ ] = positions[h.vert2+0];
               coords[ index ++ ] = positions[h.vert2+1];
               coords[ index ++ ] = positions[h.vert2+2];
           }
           geometry2.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( coords, 3 ) );

           // Build Line object from the geometry
           return new THREE.Line(geometry2, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } ), THREE.LinePieces);
       }

       // Build geometry 
       var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
       geometry.computeFaceNormals();
       geometry.computeTangents();
       geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry);
       var line = BufferEdgesHelper(geometry);

       // Build shader
       var vertexShader = document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent;
       var fragmentShader = document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent;

       var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { 
           uniforms: {}, 
           attributes: {
               'center': { type: 'v3', value: null,  boundTo: 'faceVertices' }
           }, 
           vertexShader: vertexShader, 
           fragmentShader: fragmentShader 
       } );

       var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

       // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       // (Boilerplate)

       var scene = new THREE.Scene();
       var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 
                                                window.innerWidth / 
                                                window.innerHeight, 
                                                0.1, 1000);

       var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
       renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
       document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
       scene.add(cube);
       scene.add(line);

       camera.position.z = 5;

       var render = function () {
           requestAnimationFrame(render);
           cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
           cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
           line.rotation.x = cube.rotation.x;
           line.rotation.y = cube.rotation.y;
           renderer.render(scene, camera);
       };

       render();
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r100/three.min.js"></script>
   <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
       attribute vec3 center;
       varying vec3 vCenter;
       
       void main() {

           vCenter = center;
           gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

       }
   </script>
   <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">
       #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives: enable

       varying vec3 vCenter;

       float edgeFactorTri() {

           vec3 d = fwidth(vCenter.xyz);
           vec3 a3 = smoothstep(vec3(0.0), d * 1.5, vCenter.xyz);
           return min(min(a3.x, a3.y), a3.z);

       }

       void main() {
           gl_FragColor.rgb = mix(vec3(1.0), vec3(0.2), edgeFactorTri());
           gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
       }
   </script>
   ```
3. Attempted to adapt the `BufferEdgesHelper` to save its results in a custom attribute (`isEdge`), then read that attribute in the custom shader when deciding whether to render the edge or not: http://jsfiddle.net/4tf4c6sf/ \

   ```js
       function BufferEdgesHelper(geometry) {

           var positions = geometry.attributes.position.array;
           var normals = geometry.attributes.normal.array;

           // Build new attribute storing barycentric coordinates
           // for each vertex
           var centers = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array( 3 * positions.length ), 3);
           for( var f = 0; f < positions.length; f += 9 ) {
               centers.array[ f + 0 ] = 1;
               centers.array[ f + 1 ] = 0;
               centers.array[ f + 2 ] = 0;

               centers.array[ f + 3 ] = 0;
               centers.array[ f + 4 ] = 1;
               centers.array[ f + 5 ] = 0;

               centers.array[ f + 6 ] = 0;
               centers.array[ f + 7 ] = 0;
               centers.array[ f + 8 ] = 1;
           }
           geometry.addAttribute( 'center', centers );


           // Hash all the edges and remember which face they're associated with
           // (Adapted from THREE.EdgesHelper)
           function sortFunction ( a, b ) { 
               if (a[0] - b[0] != 0) {
                   return (a[0] - b[0]);
               } else if (a[1] - b[1] != 0) { 
                   return (a[1] - b[1]);
               } else { 
                   return (a[2] - b[2]);
               }
           }
           var edge = [ 0, 0 ];
           var hash = {};
           var face;
           var numEdges = 0;

           for (var i = 0; i < positions.length/9; i++) {
               var a = i * 9 
               face = [ [ positions[a+0], positions[a+1], positions[a+2] ] ,
                        [ positions[a+3], positions[a+4], positions[a+5] ] ,
                        [ positions[a+6], positions[a+7], positions[a+8] ] ];
               for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                   var k = (j + 1) % 3;
                   var b = j * 3
                   var c = k * 3
                   edge[ 0 ] = face[ j ];
                   edge[ 1 ] = face[ k ];
                   edge.sort( sortFunction );
                   key = edge[0] + ' | ' + edge[1];
                   if ( hash[ key ] == undefined ) {
                       hash[ key ] = { vert1: a + b, vert2: a + c, face1: a, face2: undefined };
                       numEdges++;
                   } else { 
                       hash[ key ].face2 = a;
                   }
               }
           }

           // Build a new geometry containing only the "hard" edges,
           // but also save this information to a custom attribute 
           // of the original geometry
           var isEdge = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array( 3 * positions.length ), 1);
           var geometry2 = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
           var coords = new Float32Array( numEdges * 2 * 3 );
           var index = 0;
           for (key in hash) {
               h = hash[key];
               
               // ditch any edges that are bordered by two coplanar faces
               if ( h.face2 !== undefined ) {
                   normal1 = new THREE.Vector3(normals[h.face1+0], normals[h.face1+1], normals[h.face1+2]);
                   normal2 = new THREE.Vector3(normals[h.face2+0], normals[h.face2+1], normals[h.face2+2]);
                   if ( normal1.dot( normal2 ) >= 0.9999 ) { continue; }
               }

               // save edge vertices to the new geometry
               coords[ index ++ ] = positions[h.vert1+0];
               coords[ index ++ ] = positions[h.vert1+1];
               coords[ index ++ ] = positions[h.vert1+2];

               coords[ index ++ ] = positions[h.vert2+0];
               coords[ index ++ ] = positions[h.vert2+1];
               coords[ index ++ ] = positions[h.vert2+2];

               // mark edge vertices as such in a custom attribute
               isEdge.array[h.vert1+0] = 1.0;
               isEdge.array[h.vert1+1] = 1.0;
               isEdge.array[h.vert1+2] = 1.0;
               isEdge.array[h.vert2+0] = 1.0;
               isEdge.array[h.vert2+1] = 1.0;
               isEdge.array[h.vert2+2] = 1.0;
           }
           geometry2.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( coords, 3 ) );
           geometry.addAttribute( 'isEdge', isEdge );

           return new THREE.Line(geometry2, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } ), THREE.LinePieces);
       }

       // Build geometry 
       var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
       geometry.computeFaceNormals();
       geometry.computeTangents();
       geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry);
       var line = BufferEdgesHelper(geometry);

       // Build shader
       var vertexShader = document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent;
       var fragmentShader = document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent;

       var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { 
           uniforms: {}, 
           attributes: {
               'center': { type: 'v3', value: null,  boundTo: 'faceVertices' },
               'isEdge': { type: 'f', value: null }
           }, 
           vertexShader: vertexShader, 
           fragmentShader: fragmentShader 
       } );

       var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

       // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       // (Boilerplate)

       var scene = new THREE.Scene();
       var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 
                                                window.innerWidth / 
                                                window.innerHeight, 
                                                0.1, 1000);

       var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
       renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
       document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
       scene.add(cube);
       scene.add(line);

       camera.position.z = 5;

       var render = function () {
           requestAnimationFrame(render);
           cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
           cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
           line.rotation.x = cube.rotation.x;
           line.rotation.y = cube.rotation.y;
           renderer.render(scene, camera);
       };

       render();
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r100/three.min.js"></script>

   <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
       attribute vec3 center;
       varying vec3 vCenter;
       
       attribute float isEdge;
       varying float vIsEdge;

       void main() {

           vCenter = center;
           vIsEdge = isEdge;
           gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

       }
   </script>
   <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">
       #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives: enable

       varying vec3 vCenter;
       varying float vIsEdge;

       float edgeFactorTri() {

           vec3 d = fwidth(vCenter.xyz);
           vec3 a3 = smoothstep(vec3(0.0), d * 1.5, vCenter.xyz);
           return min(min(a3.x, a3.y), a3.z);

       }

       void main() {
           if (vIsEdge > 0.5) {
               gl_FragColor.rgb = mix(vec3(1.0), vec3(0.2), edgeFactorTri());
           } else {
               gl_FragColor.rgb = vec3(0.2);
           }
           gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
       }
   </script>
   ```

The first two fiddles work as expected, showing (1) the white wireframe edge rendered by the shader, then (2) the white edges from the shader plus the red "hard" edges from the `Line`. However, (3) gives the same results as (2), rather than using the `isEdge` attribute to decide whether to draw a line or not; I can't figure out why that is.

Any idea how to fix this so that *only* the hard edges are rendered by the shader (e.g. the red and white lines overlap)?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the edge-pruning algorithm needs to be tuned a bit. You need to save the vertices for both faces, not just the first face, because you need to alter both triangles associated with the edge for them to render properly using barycentric coordinates.

Second, I think that this can be done without a new `isEdge` variable, but just by altering `centers`.

The normal setup for barycentric coordinates is having the three vertices be `(1,0,0)`, `(0,1,0)`, `(0,0,1)`. However, if we want to not draw the edge between vertices 0 and 1, we can change this to `(1,0,1)`, `(0,1,1)`, `(0,0,1)`, so that no matter how far from vertex 2 we get, `vCenter.z` is always 1. Then, we can start with `centers` filled with ones (all edges disabled), and enable the edges one by one as we see which edges should stay.

With that in mind, I've reworked your code a bit. I've stripped out the edge object and just left the barycentric stuff. below is the link to js fiddle

I found that the call to compute normals should be done after the conversion to `BufferGeometry`. Calling `.fromGeometry` does indeed duplicate the vertices, but the normals have to be recomputed if the object you're working has shared vertices.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gangula/rnv1xtu2/1/

```js
function setUpBarycentricCoordinates(geometry) {
  
    var positions = geometry.attributes.position.array;
    var normals = geometry.attributes.normal.array;

    // Build new attribute storing barycentric coordinates
    // for each vertex
    var centers = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(positions.length), 3);
    // start with all edges disabled
    for (var f = 0; f < positions.length; f++) { centers.array[f] = 1; }
    geometry.addAttribute( 'center', centers );

    // Hash all the edges and remember which face they're associated with
    // (Adapted from THREE.EdgesHelper)
    function sortFunction ( a, b ) { 
        if (a[0] - b[0] != 0) {
            return (a[0] - b[0]);
        } else if (a[1] - b[1] != 0) { 
            return (a[1] - b[1]);
        } else { 
            return (a[2] - b[2]);
        }
    }
    var edge = [ 0, 0 ];
    var hash = {};
    var face;
    var numEdges = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < positions.length/9; i++) {
        var a = i * 9 
        face = [ [ positions[a+0], positions[a+1], positions[a+2] ] ,
                 [ positions[a+3], positions[a+4], positions[a+5] ] ,
                 [ positions[a+6], positions[a+7], positions[a+8] ] ];
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            var k = (j + 1) % 3;
            var b = j * 3;
            var c = k * 3;
            edge[ 0 ] = face[ j ];
            edge[ 1 ] = face[ k ];
            edge.sort( sortFunction );
            key = edge[0] + ' | ' + edge[1];
            if ( hash[ key ] == undefined ) {
                hash[ key ] = {
                  face1: a,
                  face1vert1: a + b,
                  face1vert2: a + c,
                  face2: undefined,
                  face2vert1: undefined,
                  face2vert2: undefined
                };
                numEdges++;
            } else { 
                hash[ key ].face2 = a;
                hash[ key ].face2vert1 = a + b;
                hash[ key ].face2vert2 = a + c;
            }
        }
    }

    var index = 0;
    for (key in hash) {
        h = hash[key];
        
        // ditch any edges that are bordered by two coplanar faces
        var normal1, normal2;
        if ( h.face2 !== undefined ) {
            normal1 = new THREE.Vector3(normals[h.face1+0], normals[h.face1+1], normals[h.face1+2]);
            normal2 = new THREE.Vector3(normals[h.face2+0], normals[h.face2+1], normals[h.face2+2]);
            if ( normal1.dot( normal2 ) >= 0.9999 ) { continue; }
        }

        // mark edge vertices as such by altering barycentric coordinates
        var otherVert;
        otherVert = 3 - (h.face1vert1 / 3) % 3 - (h.face1vert2 / 3) % 3;
        centers.array[h.face1vert1 + otherVert] = 0;
        centers.array[h.face1vert2 + otherVert] = 0;
        
        otherVert = 3 - (h.face2vert1 / 3) % 3 - (h.face2vert2 / 3) % 3;
        centers.array[h.face2vert1 + otherVert] = 0;
        centers.array[h.face2vert2 + otherVert] = 0;
    }
}

// Build geometry 
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry);
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
setUpBarycentricCoordinates(geometry);

// Build shader
var vertexShader = document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent;
var fragmentShader = document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent;

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { 
    uniforms: {}, 
    // attributes: {
    //     'center': { type: 'v3', value: null,  boundTo: 'faceVertices' }
    // }, 
    vertexShader: vertexShader, 
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader 
} );

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// (Boilerplate)

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 
                                         window.innerWidth / 
                                         window.innerHeight, 
                                         0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r100/three.min.js"></script>
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
    attribute vec3 center;
    varying vec3 vCenter;

    void main() {
        vCenter = center;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
</script>
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">
    #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives: enable

    varying vec3 vCenter;

    float edgeFactorTri() {
        vec3 d = fwidth(vCenter.xyz);
        vec3 a3 = smoothstep(vec3(0.0), d * 1.5, vCenter.xyz);
        return min(min(a3.x, a3.y), a3.z);
    }

    void main() {
        gl_FragColor.rgb = mix(vec3(1.0), vec3(0.2), edgeFactorTri());
        gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, the jsfiddle seems broken :)

Comment: found this reference that might be helpful: http://strattonbrazil.blogspot.com/2011/09/single-pass-wireframe-rendering_10.html

Comment: I updated the fiddle with `three.js r100` and it started working: http://jsfiddle.net/rnv1xtu2/1/